# R list with dataframes have name in the whole output, but doesn't have name individually

Tags: r, list, names

Think I don't have to make reproducible examples because I think it's just a phenomenon..?or nomenclature? algorithm? that I don't know. sorry i'm new to R.

I have a list of dataframes. maybe 2-dimension? [[67]] [3].

the list itself structually  has 67 rows, so

```
length(example_DF)
```

gives me 67. of course.

and each of these 67 big rooms(? people always explan the concept of [[n]] as a big room, so...)

have three small rooms. so

```
length(example_DF[[1]])
```

is 3.

those three small room names are

```
names(wholeData_Merged_Splitted[[1]])
```

```
'0''1''2'
```

one small room([[n]][m]) is a single dataframe 94 x 11, so

```
length(example_DF[[1]][1])
```

is 1.

I printed the whole `example_DF` and those 67 big rooms *did have names* in the console output.

```
example_DF
```

```
1.$'0'
(dataframe output which is the same as [[1]][1])
$'1'
(dataframe [[1]][2])
$'2'
(dataframe [[1]][3])
2.$'0'
(dataframe [[2]][1])
$'1'
(dataframe [[2]][2])
$'2'
(dataframe [[2]][3])

... 

67.$'0'
(dataframe [[67]][1])
$'1'
(dataframe [[67]][2])
$'2'
(dataframe [[67]][3])
```

This is totally normal I think.

But when I tried to have a look at the whole example_DF dataframe, the name values are NULL.

```
names(example_DF)
```

```
NULL
```

I expected '1' '2' '3' ... '67'. That full output says that. but why is it..?

I tried `rownames()` also, but the result is the same NULL value.

In the docs, return value of the function `names()` is *a character vector of up to the same length as x, or NULL*. Then is the [[n]] name is really `NULL` value but the output had to have some numbers so I got `1. 2. ... 67.` instantlly?

Comment: You 67 dataframe are not named in the list, that is why it is returned as NULL. If you want to see the names of each of the data frame e.g. `names(example_DF[[1]])`, `names(example_DF[[1]])`, you can try `lapply(example_DF, names)` instead.

Comment: Oh. So those 1~67 were not names... thank you.

Comment: Nope. Those are just position value.